# Access to value of object inside array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I have a complicated response from an `http` request as shown below:

```
"rates": [
            {
                "non_refundable": false,
                "no_of_rooms": 1,
                "includes_wifi": false,
                "includes_boarding": true,
                "has_promotions": true,
                "group_code": "xgirbylkwb6xtg",
                "currency": "INR",
                "cancellation_policy": {
                    "under_cancellation": false,
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "from": "2016-12-25T00:00:00",
                            "flat_fee": 20309.01,
                            "currency": "INR"
                        }
                    ],
                    "cancel_by_date": "2016-12-24T00:00:00",
                    "amount_type": "value"
                }
           }
      ]
```

Rates length is between 6-20 inside another array with length of around 200.
The `"cancellation_policy"`shows up only if `"non_refundable": false`.

How I can access `"from": "2016-12-25T00:00:00"` and change the format with Moment JS and how I can access `"flat_fee": 20309.01`?

I tried using `angular.forEach` already but it defines only the value of last array .

I tried this already:

```
 if ($scope.data[i].rates[j].non_refundable == false) {
for (var d = $scope.data[i].rates[j].cancellation_policy.details.length - 1; d >= 0; d--) {
```

But I had no success.

**ps:**
The value should show on `$mdDialog`

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you asking about how to loop in an array?

Comment: @AbhinavJain actually I would like to loop in array in object that its inside array but all I get just the last value

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop under details, just do it like this :

```
var startdate = $scope.data[i].rates[j].cancellation_policy.details[0].from;
var new_date = moment(startdate).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
var other = $scope.data[i].rates[j].cancellation_policy.details[0].flat_fee;
```

Comment: I try `var other = $scope.data[i].rates[j].cancellation_policy.details[0].flat_fee;` but still get the last value only and in some part `"details"` length is 2 or 3 how I can get those value??

Comment: Did you miss something on json object?

Comment: from object I don't think so I lost way some part in my codes that I can't figure out

Comment: may be in your object you got different object under details did you got other possibility format?

Comment: all objects are from outsource http request and this is from documentation : `details array List of cancellation windows and applicable charges. Refer policy details below.` I try so many way now for almost 2 days

Comment: @John Doe just call the api and console.log(thebaseofjson) or do multiple request to see if any change between us.

Comment: I did multiple request as your suggestion now `details` return undefine I think from api server return deffrent each time .
thanks i send email to api support and wait for they response ASAP

Comment: yes you need it or look if the api got a schema to reference of data serving.